# Rails 5.2 Active Storage purging/deleting attachements won't delete Blob or Attachent records

Tags: rails-activestorage, ruby-on-rails-5.2

I am using rails 5.2 and I am trying to set up Active Storage with Amazon S3. My application has full access to S3 and I am able to attach an `avatar` image to a `user`. But when I try to delete the avatar, I run into the following issues:

```
> user.avatar.attached? #true`
> user.avatar.purge
   S3 Storage (697.9ms) Deleted file from key: Ns1KBRzdgxLNnY31sH72vT5t
   S3 Storage (227.0ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/Ns1KBRzdgxLNnY31sH72vT5t/
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied: Access Denied
```

Then when I inspect the bucket, the file was actually deleted, but looking in the database, both `Blob`, and the `Attachment` records are still present.

Any ideas why this is happening?

**EDIT**
I made some updates in my IAM permissions following the advice from the accepted answer. These are the items that I updated:

- Attached a policy to my IAM user, instead of my s3 bucket.
- Listed all the required actions.
- Add the whole bucket in the resource field, not just all objects.

In the end my policy json looked like this:

```
    {
        "Version": "2012-10-17",
        "Statement": [
            {
                "Sid": "VisualEditor0",
                "Effect": "Allow",
                "Action": [
                    "s3:PutObject",
                    "s3:GetObject",
                    "s3:ListBucket",
                    "s3:DeleteObject"
                ],
                "Resource": [
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                    "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The S3 account you use for Active Storage must have the `s3:DeleteObject` permission for the entire bucket. (As specified in the [Active Storage guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#amazon-s3-service), it must also have the `s3:ListBucket`, `s3:PutObject`, and `s3:GetObject` permissions.)

Comment: Thank you, I found what the cause was. In my case, the resource field in the policy was missing the value for the whole bucket. This is the resource field from my policy `"Resource": [
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket/*",
                "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket"
            ]`

Comment: @felix can you put it as another answer - it's hard to read in a comment

Comment: @stevec I edited the question including the solution and the code in the comment, so it can be better read.