# I have full S3 permissions, confirmed with simulator, but getting an access denied using AWS S3 SDK for Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I am attaching images to Ruby on Rails objects that simply uploads an image into S3. When the rails record is destroyed, it's supposed to delete the S3 object with `dependent: :purge_later`

It seems like this is actually working, but I'm getting an error in the console that doesn't seem to make sense. For example, when the object is deleted, here's what Rails shows in the console:

```
Performing ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: de894c78-5398-4b6e-b0c0-6b095063b97f) from Async(default) with arguments: #<GlobalID:0x00005620ed43c768 @uri=#<URI::GID gid://vspm/ActiveStorage::Blob/2899>>          
   (1.2ms)  BEGIN           
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Exists (1.6ms)  SELECT  1 AS one FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."blob_id" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["blob_id", 2899], ["LIMIT", 1]]           
  ActiveStorage::Blob Destroy (1.7ms)  DELETE FROM "active_storage_blobs" WHERE "active_storage_blobs"."id" = $1  [["id", 2899]]           
   (2.0ms)  COMMIT          
  ActiveStorage::Attachment Load (1.4ms)  SELECT  "active_storage_attachments".* FROM "active_storage_attachments" WHERE "active_storage_attachments"."record_id" = $1 AND "active_storage_attachments"."record_type" = $2 AND "active_storage_attachments"."name" = $3 LIMIT $4  [["record_id", 2899], ["record_type", "ActiveStorage::Blob"], ["name", "preview_i
mage"], ["LIMIT", 1]]       
[Aws::S3::Client 204 0.288365 0 retries] delete_object(bucket:"my-bucket-name",key:"LiyJQK82y2XggmLHBXmcmukv")     
    
  S3 Storage (290.1ms) Deleted file from key: LiyJQK82y2XggmLHBXmcmukv      
[Aws::S3::Client 403 0.065125 0 retries] list_objects_v2(prefix:"variants/LiyJQK82y2XggmLHBXmcmukv/",bucket:"my-bucket-name") Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied      
    
  S3 Storage (66.7ms) Deleted files by key prefix: variants/LiyJQK82y2XggmLHBXmcmukv/   
Error performing ActiveStorage::PurgeJob (Job ID: de894c78-5398-4b6e-b0c0-6b095063b97f) from Async(default) in 374.9ms: Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied):         
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/raise_response_errors.rb:17:in `call'      
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.88.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/plugins/sse_cpk.rb:24:in `call' 
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.88.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/plugins/dualstack.rb:36:in `call'         
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.88.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/plugins/accelerate.rb:50:in `call'        
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/jsonvalue_converter.rb:22:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/idempotency_token.rb:19:in `call' 
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/param_converter.rb:26:in `call'     
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/request_callback.rb:71:in `call' 
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/plugins/response_paging.rb:12:in `call'     
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/seahorse/client/plugins/response_target.rb:24:in `call'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/seahorse/client/request.rb:72:in `send_request'   
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.88.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/client.rb:7878:in `list_objects_v2'  
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.88.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/bucket.rb:814:in `block in objects'       
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/resources/collection.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/resources/collection.rb:101:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-core-3.112.0/lib/aws-sdk-core/resources/collection.rb:101:in `block in non_empty_batches'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.88.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/object_summary.rb:1343:in `each'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.88.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/object_summary.rb:1343:in `each' 
/usr/local/bundle/gems/aws-sdk-s3-1.88.2/lib/aws-sdk-s3/object_summary.rb:1343:in `batch_delete!'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-5.2.4/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb:55:in `block in delete_prefixed'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-5.2.4/lib/active_storage/service.rb:124:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-5.2.4/lib/active_storage/service/s3_service.rb:54:in `delete_prefixed'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-5.2.4/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:174:in `delete'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-5.2.4/app/models/active_storage/blob.rb:182:in `purge'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activestorage-5.2.4/app/jobs/active_storage/purge_job.rb:8:in `perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/execution.rb:39:in `block in perform_now'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/i18n-1.8.9/lib/i18n.rb:314:in `with_locale'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/translation.rb:9:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Translation>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:26:in `block (4 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `block in instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications/instrumenter.rb:23:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/notifications.rb:168:in `instrument'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:25:in `block (3 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:46:in `block in tag_logger'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `block in tagged'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:28:in `tagged'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/tagged_logging.rb:71:in `tagged'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:46:in `tag_logger'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/logging.rb:22:in `block (2 levels) in <module:Logging>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/execution.rb:38:in `perform_now'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/execution.rb:24:in `block in execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:109:in `block in run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:28:in `block (4 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:73:in `block in wrap'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/execution_wrapper.rb:87:in `wrap'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/reloader.rb:72:in `wrap'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/railtie.rb:27:in `block (3 levels) in <class:Railtie>'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `instance_exec'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:118:in `block in run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activesupport-5.2.4/lib/active_support/callbacks.rb:136:in `run_callbacks'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/execution.rb:22:in `execute'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/activejob-5.2.4/lib/active_job/queue_adapters/async_adapter.rb:70:in `perform'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:363:in `run_task'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:352:in `block (3 levels) in create_worker'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:335:in `loop'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:335:in `block (2 levels) in create_worker'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `catch'
/usr/local/bundle/gems/concurrent-ruby-1.1.8/lib/concurrent-ruby/concurrent/executor/ruby_thread_pool_executor.rb:334:in `block in create_worker'
```

When I check S3, the object is actually no longer there, so I'm not quite sure why it's failing here. From my understanding, the reason it's failing is because it's not able to perform ListObjects; however, here's a copy of my S3 policy:

```
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    },
```

Shouldn't this mean I should be able to do whatever to this bucket?

[This issue](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50339851/rails-5-2-active-storage-purging-deleting-attachements-wont-delete-blob-or-atta) seems similar to mine, but I am using a secret key and access key ID that is tied to this policy, which has permissions to do everything on S3

I have even tried to do a very basic task, such as just listing the objects, but that failed with an AccessDenied error as well:

```
irb(main):029:0> credentials = Aws::Credentials.new(access_key, secret_access_key)
=> #<Aws::Credentials access_key_id="[obfuscated-for-stackoverflow]">
irb(main):030:0> s3 = Aws::S3::Resource.new(region: region, credentials: credentials)
=> #<Aws::S3::Resource:0x0000562375751798 @client=#<Aws::S3::Client>>
irb(main):031:0> bucket = s3.bucket(@bucket_name)
=> #<Aws::S3::Bucket:0x000056237544e140 @name="my-bucket-name", @data=nil, @client=#<Aws::S3::Client>, @waiter_block_warned=false, @resolved_region="us-east-1", @arn=nil>
irb(main):032:0> bucket.objects.first
[Aws::S3::Client 403 0.27261 0 retries] list_objects_v2(bucket:"my-bucket-name") Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied Access Denied

Traceback (most recent call last):
Aws::S3::Errors::AccessDenied (Access Denied)
irb(main):033:0>
```

(my-bucket-name is just obfuscated for this question)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Shouldn't this mean I should be able to do whatever to this bucket?

No it doesn't. Your policy applies to only **objects in the bucket**, not the bucket itself, due to `/*`. The `/*` refers to objects only. To have the policy apply to bucket as well you need:

```
    {
      "Action": "s3:*",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name",
        "arn:aws:s3:::my-bucket-name/*"
      ],
      "Effect": "Allow"
    }
```

The above policy allows for everything, so be careful how you use it.

Comment: Gotcha. Understood. So the reason the error is failing is because it's trying to list objects on the bucket, rather than accessing a particular object within the bucket? If so, then I think I need to turn my troubleshooting into figuring out why Rails is doing this. Thanks for confirming this!

Comment: @LewlSauce `ListObjects` action is for buckets, not objects. So in your original policy, `ListObjects` does not work.

Comment: @LewlSauce Try with new policy and see how it goes. There can be other permissions needed, depending on your setup. For example, if objects are encrypted using KMS, you may need extra KMS permissions.

Comment: That did it! I added the `s3:ListBucket` permission to the bucket and looks like we're all set! Thanks so much again!